# How to make the player jump up automatically when standing on a specific block in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

(please forgive me for my bad coding skills)

So im trying to make a jumppad in unity where, if the player stands on the jump pad, the player automatically gets shot up into the sky.

```
float height = 50f;

else if (onJumpPad)
        {
            while (true) {
                velocity.y += 1;
                height -= 1;

                if (height == 0)
                {
                    height = 50f;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

above is the half-working code. I have to jump ON the jump pad to make the player get shot up into the sky.

Any help is appreciated.

(I know that the height variable should not belong in the middle of the else if statement, I just wrote it for demonstration purposes).

full code here = https://pastebin.com/3ZVu5bUq

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need kind of jump pad. So First of all don't forget to add a collider on block as much height and width as you need. Then you can check with OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter. For Example:-

I have a block named jumpPad. I added a box collider on that with full of width and with minimum height. I didn't checked IsTrigger so I have to use OnCollisionEnter. Now what I will write in code inside player script is:-

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
       if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("jumpPad")
       {
           GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.Up * force);
       }
    }
```

In this code force is already declared somewhere in script. Also make sure to give block a tag if you are using CompareTag or .tag == "jumpPad". Also you need to add rigidbody component to player object.

Comment: well the thing is, RigidBody components doesnt really go well with my player.
I created my player using GameObjects, and a 3D object. I tested it before and the player just fell.

Comment: so you can go with transform.position but rigidbody is recommended. You said you created using GameObjects and a 3D object. What you can do is create an empty and make the player his child. Attach rigidbody to the empty object and also put this script on that empty object. I am pretty sure it will work

Comment: It doesnt work. I created another script and added the code you suggested.

https://imgur.com/a/3crDwdK

Comment: You could try to attach rigidbody in player as that is containing everything and add script there and are you sure you are following everything? block has collider and if you are using same code as my you gave block the tag i provided and also block collider isn't checked as IsTrigger